# How to prepare (compress/zip) a plugin to enable updating instead of adding new instance?

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, updates, ziparchive

I created my own plugins and install/update them by uploading the zip file in the dashboard.
That worked well, but suddenly<sup>1</sup> a new instance of the plugin gets added instead of updating the already installed one. Before WP would ask "do you want to replace version X with version Y", but that dialog does not appear anymore.

I had this issue before, but back then I had the date and version in the name of the zip file. Ever since I always use the same name for the zip file (e.g. `my-plugin.zip`), it used to update the plugin.

Now WP creates new directories `my-plugin-1`, `my-plugin-2`, ... when updating.

**Is there a best practice for creating the zip files?

What let's WP decide whether to install a new instance or update?**

### Update

It seems that it now works again as before, the zip files are recognizes as updates. I have no clue why it stop working nor why it started working again.
**I would still be interested on how to best prepare (compress/zip) plugins to enable an update instead of adding a new instance.**
Is it the name of the zip file? The name of the zipped folder? The name in the style.css manifest?

---

<sup>1</sup> I'm sure there is a good reason for it, but I don't know yet what changed that caused this

Answer (score 0):

This is the default behaviour for WordPress. But there is a plugin called **"Easy theme and plugin upgrades"** that handles this for plugin and template updates: https://de.wordpress.org/plugins/easy-theme-and-plugin-upgrades/

After installing the plugin, you can just upload a new zip and it wont't install another plugin/theme instance. Instead, the plugin generates a backup of the older version and overwrites the plugin folder.

Comment: [Since 5.5 this is a core feature](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/wordpress-5-5-feature-update-by-uploading-zip-files/), so no, it is not "default behaviour" anymore.

Comment: It was definitely not "default behaviour" for the last months, since I updated plugins and themes this way multiple times (without any extra plugins). @kero did something change lately that deactivates the functionality again. I noticed this now on 2 different WP websites

Comment: That's interesting, never noticed that change. Nevertheless, the mentioned plugin just works fine.